# disable Bootstrap's Collapse open/close animation

Tags: javascript, animation, twitter-bootstrap

Any trick to disable the open/close animation of Collapse groups ?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

For Bootstrap **3** and **4** it's

```
.collapsing {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can confirm, this works for bootstrap 3. I ended up disabling the transition as it is fairly slow on mobile devices. Not sure why.

Comment: on mobile there still is a small deley because of this line from bootstrap.js:  "Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION = 350"  
change the transition duration value and the delay will be fixed.

Comment: What about -moz-transition and -o-transition?

Comment: I added `display: none` to avoid the last collapsing artefact.

Comment: You can also add another CSS class to disable the animation on certain elements. Something like `.no-animation.collapsing {...}` in your CSS

Comment: while this disables the animation, as per the OP's request, it keeps the opening delay.  Is it possible to reduce that delay to 0?

Comment: Works like a charm in Bootstrap v4.1.
However, how to resolve that 0.5 ms jerk for bootstrap and reactJS combination?

Comment: @SamAxe I just had the same problem, and Cristina Cristea gives the solution above. Reduce the delay value. To override the value without changing the bootstrap code, run `$.fn.collapse.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION = 0;` after bootstrap.js has loaded.

Comment: I suggest to put also height: auto !important; on the collapsing class, to avoid bootstrap js to force an height and give a strange bounce effect

Comment: And for bootstrap 5 please ?

Comment: It works with bootstrap 5 as well :)

Answer (score 30):

#### `Bootstrap 2` CSS solution:

```
.collapse {  transition: height 0.01s; }
```

**NB**: setting `transition: none` disables the collapse functionnality.

---

#### `Bootstrap 4` solution:

```
.collapsing {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you find the **1px** jump before expanding and after collapsing when using the CSS solution a bit annoying, here's a simple **JavaScript** solution for **Bootstrap 3**...

Just add this somewhere in your code:

```
$(document).ready(
    $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }),
    $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $($(this).data('target')).toggleClass('in');
    })
);
```

Comment: For me the issue was not only with the CSS transition itself, but with the javascript that changes the height. The overall experience was lacking on mobile and using the above JS code solved it for me.

Comment: This solves my problem aswell but it prevents the navbar from closing if you click outside, (I have a click event for that)..

Comment: Awesome solution! This results in a totally smooth transition. No flickering at all.

Comment: Best Solution Yet, CSS was not working in my case.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe not a direct answer to the question, but a recent addition to the [official documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/16157/files) describes how jQuery can be used to disable transitions **entirely** just by:

```
$.support.transition = false
```

---

Setting the `.collapsing` CSS transitions to none [as mentioned in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22428493/1678416) removed the animation. But this — in Firefox and Chromium for me — creates an unwanted visual issue on collapse of the navbar.

For instance, visit the Bootstrap [navbar example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) and add the CSS from the accepted answer:

```
.collapsing {
     -webkit-transition: none;
     transition: none;
}
```

What I currently see is when the navbar collapses, the bottom border of the navbar momentarily becomes two pixels instead of one, then disconcertingly jumps back to one. Using jQuery, this artifact doesn't appear.

Comment: The one downside is this would disable transitions globally, which might not be desired.

Comment: Plain `$.support.transition = false` after loading `bootstrap.min.js` was not enough, but `$(function() { $.support.transition = false; })` did the trick for me.