# Show/hide a Bootstrap Collapse element with no animation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I am aware that you can disable the collapse animation completely as is described in the accepted answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119912/disable-bootstraps-collapse-open-close-animation)

But is there any way that I can disable the animation for a `.collapse('show')` or `.collapse('hide')` call as a one off? I would really like to be able to do something like this:

```
.collapse({'show', 
    animation : false        
});
```

But this option doesn't seem to exist.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so this is the solution I came up with using JQuery

```
$("myCollapseElement").addClass("in");
```

will expand the element with no animation and

```
$("myCollapseElement").removeClass("in");
```

will collapse the element with no animation.

This solution suits my purposes, however there is a feature request to be able to do it the way I suggested in my question: [Bootstrap Issue enable/disable animation of Collapse on a per-show/hide basis](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18127).

So when the guys over at twitter do release this feature I will update my answer. But for the time being, using JQuery to add the bootstrap class `in` works for me.

Comment: The classes have been changed in Boostrap 4, so here's the code that will work for that version:
`$("myCollapseElement").addClass("show");` to show the element without animation
`$("myCollapseElement").removeClass("show");` to hide the element without animation

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the animation then why to use the `collapse` feature at all. Just use JQuery's `hide` & `show`.

```
$(".my-prev-collapse-element").hide();
$(".my-prev-collapse-element").show();
```

Based on the suggestion from @Redtama, the animation can directly be prevented from:

```
$("my-prev-collapse-element").addClass("in");
$("my-prev-collapse-element").removeClass("in");
```

to hide or show the element without animation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried using JQuery's functions but the bootstrap collapse element seems to get confused about what state it is in (e.g if I use JQuery `hide` then bootstrap still thinks the element is shown).

Comment: However your answer has helped me to find a solution because I realised I could just use JQuery to do this `$("my-prev-collapse-element").addClass("in");` You can edit your answer to this if you like since you did help me to come up with it :)

Comment: Glad, it helped. Updated the answer as you suggested.